# Self Signed Applet Can it access Local File Systems

Tags: applet, self, signed

Hi I have created a Self Signed Applet , but not able to access local files system .What have i to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to wrap your IO code inside [PrivilegedAction](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/security/PrivilegedAction.html).

Generally, you need to sign your applet with your test certificate, the user will see a warning and will have to accept the certificate when it loads the applet.

then you need to wrap your code inside a PriviligedAction. see [this](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/security/doprivileged.html) for some examples.

Comment: Hi Omry can you please explain me .What are the steps required for the applet to access my Local files .

Comment: Oh God . I tried a lot .. but could not know how to use this Privileged Action . Omry do you have any code examples etc . Only if you have post them .else it ok

Answer (score 1):

The below code is use to Add a Bouncy Castle Jar, the same way you can use it for accessing the file. AccessController java api is used.

```
AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction() {          
  public Object run() {
    try{
      Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());      // Here you can write the code for File Accesss
    }catch (Exception e) {
      return "";
    }
    return "";
  }
});
```

Comment: Will you please help others by sharing your applets complete code. thanks.