# How to register a font in iText FontFactory in self signed Java applet?

Tags: java, permissions, applet, itext

In my self signed java applet, I get following error:

```
uncaught exception: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.io.FilePermission resources/fonts/new_font.TTF read)
```

resources/fonts/new_font.TTF file is packed inside jar.

I also tried Privileged methods mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/852453/accesscontroller-doprivileged) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2498756/self-signed-applet-can-it-access-local-file-systems), but I'm still getting the error.

My code after alteration:

```
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(
        new java.security.PrivilegedAction() {
            public Object run() {
                FontFactory.register("resources/fonts/new_font.TTF", "new_font");
                return null;
            }
        }
);
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

**Edit** Very similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3830170/load-fonts-out-of-jar-file-and-create-awt-font-works-and-register-itext-font-d) without any answer.

Comment: make sure you have permission to that font from native OS. try giving 777

Comment: @org.life.java: using Cygwin on windows I set permissions to 777. Still having same problem.

Comment: Dear Jan, 

could you perhaps poste your code, how you got it to work, I also placed everything in the PrivilegedAction and it still does not work, which means, I can not show greek letters...

It works in the appletViewer, but not in the browser.

I would really apreciate this.

Best wishes,

Julia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I placed all the Font calls inside PrivilegedAction() and it works now.