# how to process file save prompt using java code

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, download

From a form in JSP I'm doing HTTP POST to a server and in return the server sends a text file to save, which results in browser opening "Save as" dialog. I want to capture the data stream through code instead of requiring the user to 'save the file'. Basically, I need to consume the content of file through java code and this should be transparent to the user.

I tried reading the request inputstream, but there is no content in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I misunderstood you, but I think you need a [**`java.applet.Applet`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/index.html). In that case, you need to use [**`java.net.URLConnection`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests) to do the POST request. Next, [save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8246471/java-applet-download-file) the stream to file.

Comment: well, I didn't use the Applet class, but using HttpClient I could process the response data.